# External links redirect to localhost [flask]

Tags: flask, jinja2

I have a small flask application that I'm running on localhost right now. most things are working fine but I've been banging my head for last few hours over this issue now - When I try to put an external link on my template, it always redirects to localhost.

I have a main.py file where I have placed a variable

`testURL = "https://www.google.com"`

On my template file, `home.html`, I place the hyperlink

`<a href="{{testURL}}", target="_blank"> More...</a>`

Clicking on that 'More...' hyperlink I wanted it to open a new tab to google.com but it's simply opening up a new tab with localhost http://127.0.0.1:5000/ - it's something very basic that I'm missing on I think.

Please point me in the right direction!
TIA

Comment: Have you passed `testURL` to the template when you render it: `render_template('home.html', testURL=testURL)`. An empty `href` would default to the page's own URL.

Comment: oh man, I knew it had to be something as basic as this, pretty awkward. Thank you, it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, you need to pass that variable to the template:

```
render_template('home.html', testURL=testURL)
```

Another useful method, if you want to send that variable to every page, is to use a context processor:

```
@app.context_processor
def processor():
  """ This function injects vars into every page """
  return dict(SITE_TITLE='My Site')
```

Then use `{{SITE_TITLE}}` in any template.

Comment: this is something that is beyond my comprehension(obviously) at this stage, but thank you for your time!

Comment: @awkward101 This will be useful when you find yourself passing the same variables to multiple `render_template` calls for things like nav bars that must appear on every page.  With the context processor you only need to pass those values once.

Comment: @v25 I have a list of links that need to be passed to the template. Since this list is dynamic, I cant pass each link individually to the template. In this situation, what can I do?

Comment: Hey, @awkward101 I'm not sure I understand.  Can you please update your question with some info on the `dynamic` list, perhaps the Python datastructure itself, and I'll show you how to implement this.

Comment: hello v25, you perhaps wanted to ask @sambam and tagged me instead